# Using Selenium to Extract Java Script

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to use `Selenium` to extract the `Javascript` in the following code snippet:

```
<div id="imageBlock_feature_div" class="feature" data-feature-name="imageBlock">
  <div id="imageBlock" class="a-section imageBlockRearch" aria-hidden="true">
  <script type="text/javascript"> P.when('A').register("ImageBlockATF", function(A){     var data = {                 'colorImages': { 'initial': [{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61a%2B2tb6CXL._SL1000_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41jyDJkFNkL._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41jyDJkFNkL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61a%2B2tb6CXL._SX342_.jpg":[342,342],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61a%2B2tb6CXL._SX385_.jpg":[385,385],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61a%2B2tb6CXL._SX425_.jpg":[425,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61a%2B2tb6CXL._SX466_.jpg":[466,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61a%2B2tb6CXL._SX522_.jpg":[522,522]},"variant":"MAIN"},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/619Zy3hzf0L._SL1000_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51JXxW9-qRL._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51JXxW9-qRL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/619Zy3hzf0L._SX342_.jpg":[342,342],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/619Zy3hzf0L._SX385_.jpg":[385,385],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/619Zy3hzf0L._SX425_.jpg":[425,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/619Zy3hzf0L._SX466_.jpg":[466,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/619Zy3hzf0L._SX522_.jpg":[522,522]},"variant":"PT01"},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xcGG8LrRL._SL1000_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/414dMuEyRJL._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/414dMuEyRJL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xcGG8LrRL._SX342_.jpg":[342,342],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xcGG8LrRL._SX385_.jpg":[385,385],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xcGG8LrRL._SX425_.jpg":[425,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xcGG8LrRL._SX466_.jpg":[466,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xcGG8LrRL._SX522_.jpg":[522,522]},"variant":"PT02"},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71KJWQdcOrL._SL1000_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51iXiwMzdSL._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51iXiwMzdSL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71KJWQdcOrL._SX342_.jpg":[342,342],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71KJWQdcOrL._SX385_.jpg":[385,385],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71KJWQdcOrL._SX425_.jpg":[425,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71KJWQdcOrL._SX466_.jpg":[466,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71KJWQdcOrL._SX522_.jpg":[522,522]},"variant":"PT03"},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61NrHnYF7fL._SL1000_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ETRy5aXsL._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ETRy5aXsL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61NrHnYF7fL._SX342_.jpg":[342,342],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61NrHnYF7fL._SX385_.jpg":[385,385],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61NrHnYF7fL._SX425_.jpg":[425,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61NrHnYF7fL._SX466_.jpg":[466,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61NrHnYF7fL._SX522_.jpg":[522,522]},"variant":"PT04"},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61aHhQsYAEL._SL1000_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ecNiAOOAL._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ecNiAOOAL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61aHhQsYAEL._SX342_.jpg":[342,342],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61aHhQsYAEL._SX385_.jpg":[385,385],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61aHhQsYAEL._SX425_.jpg":[425,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61aHhQsYAEL._SX466_.jpg":[466,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61aHhQsYAEL._SX522_.jpg":[522,522]},"variant":"PT05"},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61NW6qzcM5L._SL1000_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51qOEqY9CyL._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51qOEqY9CyL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61NW6qzcM5L._SX342_.jpg":[342,342],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61NW6qzcM5L._SX385_.jpg":[385,385],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61NW6qzcM5L._SX425_.jpg":[425,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61NW6qzcM5L._SX466_.jpg":[466,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61NW6qzcM5L._SX522_.jpg":[522,522]},"variant":"PT06"},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61DOeyBC8GL._SL1000_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41mEQqSeqXL._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41mEQqSeqXL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61DOeyBC8GL._SX342_.jpg":[342,342],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61DOeyBC8GL._SX385_.jpg":[385,385],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61DOeyBC8GL._SX425_.jpg":[425,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61DOeyBC8GL._SX466_.jpg":[466,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61DOeyBC8GL._SX522_.jpg":[522,522]},"variant":"PT07"},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UDOjrJlCL._SL1000_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51cFjif5LoL._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51cFjif5LoL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UDOjrJlCL._SX342_.jpg":[342,342],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UDOjrJlCL._SX385_.jpg":[385,385],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UDOjrJlCL._SX425_.jpg":[425,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UDOjrJlCL._SX466_.jpg":[466,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UDOjrJlCL._SX522_.jpg":[522,522]},"variant":"PT08"}]},                 'colorToAsin': {'initial': {}},                 'holderRatio': 0.77,                 'holderMaxHeight': 700,                 'weblabs' : {}                 };     A.trigger('P.AboveTheFold'); // trigger ATF event.     return data; }); </script>
  <div id="twister-main-image" class="a-hidden" customfunctionname="(function(id, state){ P.when('A').execute(function(A){ A.trigger('image-block-twister-swatch-hover', id, state); }); });"/>
  <div id="thumbs-image" class="a-hidden" customfunctionname="(function(id, state, onloadFunction){ P.when('A').execute(function(A){ A.trigger('image-block-twister-swatch-click', id, state, onloadFunction); }); });"/>
      <span class="edp-feature-declaration" data-resolver="CQResolver" data-position="0" data-edit-data-state="imageBlockEDPEditData" data-display-name="Images" data-custom-event-handler="imageBlockEDPCustomEventHandler" data-feature-container-id="imageBlockEDPOverlay" data-metadata="IMAGE" data-defects="[{"id":"defect-different-product","value":"Doesn\u2019t match product"},{"id":"defect-image-offensive","value":"Offensive or adult content"},{"id":"defect-image-extra-items","value":"Shows additional items"},{"id":"defect-image-not-clear","value":"Is not clear"},{"id":"defect-other-image-issue","value":"Other"}]" data-data-hash="" data-edp-asin="B00JM59JPG" data-edp-feature-name="imageBlock"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Basically, in  Firebug I am able to successfully identify the element using the following `XPath`:

```
.//*[@id='imageBlock_feature_div']/script
```

However when I attempt to find the element by `XPath`  in `Selenium` (I'm coding in Java) I get `NoSuchElementException`.

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":".//*[@id='imageBlock_feature_div']/script"}

The product I'm looking at on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JM59JPG).

I'm basically trying to extract all the text on the line that begins with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Is there a way to extract this text from product page?

Comment: Without seeing your selenium java code it's hard to help, but my guess is you need to wait for the element to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your Selenium code?

Have you tried using an ID selector, instead of XPATH?

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("imageBlock_feature_div"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and selenium is not throwing any such error for me

Code I have used to do so

```
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/KMASHI-10000mAh-External-Battery-Portable/dp/B00JM59JPG");
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='imageBlock_feature_div']/script"));
System.out.println(element.getAttribute("innerText"));
```

Details

Java - 1.8.x
ChromeDriver - 2.22
Chrome - 51.0.2x
Selenium - 2.53.1
OS - Windows 7